# Change sharpening settings in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

What I'm wanting to do is refine the setting for Wordpress images when they are uploaded using the media panel in Wordpress. It seems that when you upload they are somewhat blurry due to the resizing. This is possibly due to compression, but I'm looking at applying sharpening methods.

Wordpress doesn't appear to be applying any sharpening to images, but **how can I go about sharpening the images in Wordpress on upload?**

Sharpening the images prior to upload is not possibly—looking for a streamlined process by integrating a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you are searching is in wp-include/media.php

for compression it's on line 406 (already set at jpeg_qualiy = 90)

So it's pretty high by default.
Do you have another direction to check for your compression issue?
I personally never had any issues with the compression. Note that if your initila jpeg is already highly compressed then it will double compress your file.

source: wp ver. 3.1.2

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm more so looking for Sharpening not really compression. I asked for compression just for the sake of finding if Wordpress applies sharpening. However, I don't believe it does. I'm now looking for a method to start applying sharpening to images. (Updated the question to reflect)

Comment: Sorry but I can't find any info on adding a filter for sharpening. It's probably feasible but I don't know if the function is available. There's always a workaround using imagemagick but on a page with alot of images it would fail.